# TFS 2015 build stuck on GIT PUSH

Tags: git, tfs, build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've added a PowerShell task to checkout a branch and commit some changes once TFSBuild has already cloned my TFS-hosted GIT repository.

It looks like this:

```
$gitBranch = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH.Split("/")[-1]

git checkout $gitBranch
git add ../sql/
git commit -m "Updated database backup"
git push
```

Once I queue a build and it gets executed, it gets stuck on `git push`:

> 1 file changed, 1071 insertions(+)  create mode 100644 sql/web.sql

I can't figure out how can I fix this issue, because when I run the whole command in the build machine from a Powershell command line, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Does the account the agent runs as have enough permissions to push? Is it the same account you use to run the script from PS console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run a number of Powershell scripts using git and output is redirected to a log file. Git is prompting for credentials and waiting for user input.

Check that you have a properly configured credential manager in place, like [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), and the credentials are stored for the account running the build.

Comment: I'll take alook at this. Thank you!

Comment: You're right! It was exactly this. I logged in with the TFSBuild user, I cloned some TFS Git repo and I cached its credentials and it worked! ;)